# Identifying the contents of training and testing dataset after using train_test_split()

Tags: scikit-learn, training-data, train-test-split

I am doing multi-class classification using ML. After preprocessing the data, I am using train_test_split function to divide the data into training and testing dataset. Is there a way to know how many samples from each class are present in the training and testing dataset? For example:

| Class | No. of Training Samples | No. of Testing Samples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 30 | 5 |
| b | 20 | 10 |
| c | 25 | 5 |

**My Code:**

```
classes = ['a','b','c']

def pp():
  data_list=[] 
  for index,label in enumerate(classes):
    class_list=[]
    if label=='silence': 
      silence_path = os.path.join(C["dire"],'silence')
      if not os.path.exists(silence_path):
        os.mkdir(silence_path)
      silence_stride = 2000
      #sample_rate = 16000
      folder = os.path.join(C["dire"],'_background_noise_') 

      for file_ in os.listdir(folder):
        if '.wav' in file_:
          load_path = os.path.join(folder,file_)
          sample_rate,y = wavfile.read(load_path)
          for i in range(0,len(y)-sample_rate,silence_stride):
            file_path = "silence/{}_{}.wav".format(file_[:-4],i)
            y_slice = y[i:i+sample_rate]
            wavfile.write(os.path.join(C["dire"],file_path),sample_rate,y_slice)
            class_list.append(file_path)
            
    else:
      folder = os.path.join(C["dire"],label)
      for file_ in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = '{}/{}'.format(label,file_)    
        class_list.append(file_path)

    random.shuffle(class_list)              
    data_list.append(class_list)


  X = []
  Y = []
  preemphasis = 0.985
  print("Feature Extraction Started")
  for i,class_list in enumerate(data_list): 
    for j,samples in enumerate(class_list):    
      if(samples.endswith('.wav')):
        sample_rate,audio = wavfile.read(os.path.join(C["dire"],samples))
        if(audio.size<sample_rate):
            audio = np.pad(audio,(sample_rate-audio.size,0),mode="constant")
        coeff = mfccforconfidence.mfcc(audio,sample_rate,preemphasis) 
        X.append(coeff)
          #print(X)
        if(samples.split('/')[0] in classes):
            Y.append(samples.split('/')[0])
        elif(samples.split('/')[0]=='_background_noise_'):
            Y.append('silence')
        
  A = np.zeros((len(X),X[0].shape[0],X[0][0].shape[0]),dtype='object')
  
  for i in range(0,len(X)):
    A[i] = np.array(X[i])      #Converting list X into array A
    # print(A.shape)
    
  
  end1 = time.time()
  print("Time taken for feature extraction:{}sec".format(end1-start))

  
  MLB = MultiLabelBinarizer() # one hot encoding for converting labels into binary form
  
  MLB.fit(pd.Series(Y).fillna("missing").str.split(', '))
  Y_MLB = MLB.transform(pd.Series(Y).fillna("missing").str.split(', '))
  MLB.classes_        #Same like classes array
  print(Y_MLB.shape)
  Y = Y_MLB

  
  X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(X)
  X_train,X_valtest,Y_train,Y_valtest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=37)
  X_val,X_test,Y_val,Y_test = train_test_split(X_valtest,Y_valtest,test_size=0.5,random_state=37)

  print(X_train.shape,X_val.shape,X_test.shape,Y_train.shape,Y_val.shape,Y_test.shape)
```

So, basically I am using ML for audio classification. After extracting the features, I divide the data into training and testing dataset.

I hope that this piece of code will be useful to answer the question.

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as `Counter` ? `Counter(y_train)` and `Counter(y_test)`

Comment: @cucurbit I know the total count but I don't know number of samples belonging to a particular class.

Comment: If you are using `pandas.Dataframe` for `X` and `Class` is a feature/column, after `train_test_split` you can get the counts with `X_train["Class"].value_counts()` and `X_test["Class"].value_counts()`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, Thanks for your reply. I have 3D numpyarray. May be if I can convert it to a dataframe, I may use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a *"3D numpy array"*, here's a demonstration of one way you could do it.

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint,choices

# Create some data
my_data = np.array(list(zip(
    (randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)),
    (choices(["a","b","c"], k=100)),
    (randint(0,100) for _ in range(100))
  ))
)

# Show the first 5 elements
print(my_data[0:5,:])
# [['69' 'a' '38']
#  ['18' 'c' '73']
#  ['57' 'a' '50']
#  ['35' 'a' '60']
#  ['52' 'b' '1']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(my_data[:,[0,1]], my_data[:,2])

from collections import Counter

print(Counter(X_train[:,1]))
# Counter({'c': 31, 'b': 26, 'a': 18})

print(Counter(X_train[:,1])["a"])
# 18
print(Counter(X_test[:,1]))
# Counter({'b': 12, 'c': 7, 'a': 6})
```

Comment: Hi, whenever I try using counter function, it gives me TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error.

Comment: @A.Gehani If you show how you are using it, perhaps the issue could be addressed.  Please edit your question and show the code you have tried.

Comment: @A.Gehani What is `print(Y_MLB.shape)`?

Comment: @A.Gehani  What is `print(Counter("".join(_) for _ in MLB.inverse_transform(Y_train)))`?

Comment: I have used MultiLabelBinarizer() for converting labels into binary forms.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I could get the number of files from each class in training dataset.

Comment: @A.Gehani _Please_, next time include enough information in your original question so that it can be answered more easily.  It will be better for you (answered in hours, not days) and better for readers (easier understanding).  When you don't know the source of the problem, this can be difficult, and here it was all really just a matter of data representation.  Once I understood how `X`, `Y`, etc., were represented/encoded, it became clear how the `classes` could be counted.